# Replace the middle of the line based on the beginning of the line with Sed/Awk/Grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am quite new to bash/unix programing. However I have a problem that I cannot figure out. To put it in the most basic way, my csv file has a table similar to the one below.

Original:

```
TYPE1, text, text, text, Hello, text, text
TYPE2, text, text, Hello, text, text, text
```

Output:

```
TYPE1, text, text, text, RESULT1, text, text
TYPE2, text, text, RESULT2, text, text, text
```

I am trying to replace the 'Hello' string differently, based on which type of text is in the first column.

I have created code for replacing 'Hello' if it is found, but I cannot figure out how to react to the first column.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner should do what you want:

```
awk -F',' '{t=$1;sub(/TYPE/,"",t);gsub(/Hello/,"RESULT"t);print}' file
```

- the `sub()` gets the number in first column, and saves in var `t`
- the `gsub()` change all `Hello` into `RESULT` + `t`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for this.

```
sed -r 's/(^[ \t]*TYPE)([0-9])(,.*)Hello/\1\2\3RESULT\2/' filename
```

In the above command, the number after TYPE is sorround by `()` in the search text, and `\2` is used in replace text to append it after `RESULT` in the replace text. This is usually called backreferencing.

You can google about "sed search and replace", and about how to use backreferences in sed. And most importantly search and learn "regular expression".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't REALLY just want to strip of "TYPE" to be left with 1 or 2 to tack on the end of RESULT but actually have to test/set specific values:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {sub(/Hello/,($1=="TYPE1" ? "RESULT1" : "RESULT2"))} 1' file
TYPE1, text, text, text, RESULT1, text, text
TYPE2, text, text, RESULT2, text, text, text
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not make clear how you want to react on the first column. When the rules are too complicated for the solution of @sps, you can try something else:

```
sed '/^TYPE1,/ s/Hello/Result1/g;
     /^TYPE2,/ s/Hello/OtherResult/g' yourcsvfile
```

When you have a lot translations and need to change them sometimes, you would like to write them in a config file. The sed command would need to read the config file and might give problems with characters like `=/#,` and characters with special meaning in regular expressions.
Using a config file might work like

```
# Make configfile
echo "TYPE1=Result1
TYPE2=OtherResult2" > translatecsv.cfg

# test the  new cfg file, will it give valid sed commands?
sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#/^\1/ s/Hello/\2/g;#;' translatecsv.cfg

# All together now
sed "$(sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#/^\1/ s/Hello/\2/g;#;' translatecsv.cfg)" yourcsvfile
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` will work with any single digit number

```
$ awk 'match($1,/^TYPE/){sub("Hello", "RESULT"substr($1,RLENGTH+1,1))}1' file

TYPE1, text, text, text, RESULT1, text, text
TYPE2, text, text, RESULT2, text, text, text
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another AWK (well GAWK actually) using `gensub` and backreferencing:

```
awk '{print gensub(/^(TYPE)([^,]+)((.*)(Hello))*/,"\\1\\2\\4RESULT\\2","g",$0)}' file
```

If there are more than one occurrence in a record, it matches the last one where some of the other answers here match the first one.